# Trouble translating a python3 program into a pyopencl program

Tags: pyopencl

I'm trying to write a pyopencl script to compute Thomas' cyclically symmetric attractor. 
The function for which is

x' = sin(y)-bx

y' = sin(z)-by

z' = sin(x)-bz

I have written an implementation in python3 that works, albeit slowly. This is the output I want to get:

[working solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGPvZ.png)

and this is the output from my pyopencl implementation:

[broken opencl implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlqbp.png)

I believe I'm encountering some kind of rounding error or approximation error on the sine function, so i tried casting everything to a double with no success. The other possibility I can see is that I am making some mistake in outputting the values reached as the function iterates, but I don't know what it would be.

Here is the kernel in question.

```
  #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_byte_addressable_store : enable
    #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
    __kernel void thomas(__global float3 *a,
                     __global float3 *output, ulong const maxiter, float const stepSize, float const b )
    {
        int gid = get_global_id(0);

            double x = a[gid][0];
            double y = a[gid][1];
            double z = a[gid][2];
            double x1,y1,z1 = 0.0;
            for(int citer = 0; citer<maxiter;citer++){

                x1 = x+stepSize*(sin(y)-b*x);
                y1 = y+stepSize*(sin(z)-b*y);
                z1 = z+stepSize*(sin(x)-b*z);
                output[gid*maxiter+citer][0]=x1;
                output[gid*maxiter+citer][1]=y1;
                output[gid*maxiter+citer][2]=z1;
                x = x1;
                y = y1;
                z = z1;
            }



    }
```

a is an array of starting values and the output is an array with length a*maxiter

I expect the output of the pyopencl implementation to match the python3 implementation, but it seems to output a shape only in the xy plane, whose relation to the 3d shape is uncertain to me.

edit: here is the rest of the code for the offending program

```
import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl
import open3d as o3d
def calc_thomas_opencl(npoints, stepSize, maxiter, b):
    ballRadius = .5
    ctx = cl.create_some_context()
    queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
    mf = cl.mem_flags
    points = []
    for point in range(npoints):
        x1 = np.random.rand()-.5
        x2 = np.random.rand()-.5
        x3 = np.random.rand()-.5
        u = np.random.rand()
        fac = ballRadius*u**.3/(np.sqrt(x1**2+x2**2+x3**2))
        point = (x1*fac,x2*fac,x3*fac)
        points.append(point)
    a=np.array(points,dtype = np.float32)
    print(a[0])
    a_opencl = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=a)
    output = np.zeros([npoints*maxiter,3])
    output_opencl = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, output.nbytes)
    prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
    #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_byte_addressable_store : enable
    #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
    __kernel void thomas(__global float3 *a,
                     __global float3 *output, ulong const maxiter, float const stepSize, float const b )
    {
        int gid = get_global_id(0);

            double x = a[gid][0];
            double y = a[gid][1];
            double z = a[gid][2];
            double x1,y1,z1 = 0.0;
            for(int citer = 0; citer<maxiter;citer++){

                x1 = x+stepSize*(sin(y)-b*x);
                y1 = y+stepSize*(sin(z)-b*y);
                z1 = z+stepSize*(sin(x)-b*z);
                output[gid*maxiter+citer][0]=x1;
                output[gid*maxiter+citer][1]=y1;
                output[gid*maxiter+citer][2]=z1;
                x = x1;
                y = y1;
                z = z1;
            }



    }
    """).build()
    prg.thomas(queue, (npoints,), None, a_opencl,
                   output_opencl, np.uint64(maxiter), np.float32(stepSize), np.float32(b))

    cl.enqueue_copy(queue, output, output_opencl).wait()

    return output

xyz = calc_thomas_opencl(1000,.05,1000,.2)
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(xyz)
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])
```

Comment: Might be worth showing the Python code so we can check for conversion issues. And, not that it matters here (since you overwrite them before use), `double x1,y1,z1 = 0.0;` only sets the last of those variables to zero, the others may conatin arbitrary values.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I am a complete newbie in all this so I'm happy to share the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in

```
 output = np.zeros([npoints*maxiter,3])
```

it needed to be

```
 output = np.zeros([npoints*maxiter,3], dtype = np.float32)
```